# Do the Import and export features from CDR to PSD, and AI convert well?

Tags: corel-draw

CDR if your wondering is CorelDraw file format. I saw on there website that you can import and export CDR to PSD, and AI.

How good are the import and export features? Does the quality stay the same?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why do you need to export to AI or PSD?  It would probably be better to export to PDF if you're creating something for printing, since PDFs can contain vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends...

Exporting a PSD is easy, it is simply a raster image, so no problem there. Actually the export dialog box is more complete than native AI export dialog box, where you can define the size in pixels, resolution, compression settings, etc. It is similar to "export to web" dialog on Photoshop.

You can also export each layer as a layer in PS, even with transparency. But here is a catch. Transparency can be defined in the document as intrinsic to the object or as a layer mask. It is exported as an intrinsic one.

As expected, fonts and effects are rasterized.

Remember that the program to open raster images on Corel is Photopaint, that does a decent job with the layers and layered masks, but I have not tested smart objects.

But the imported PSD images into Corel Draw also retain the layers.

---

On Illustrator you can export fairly well normal curves, a logo, a diagram. But you can have issues when using internal tools, like gradient meshes, instances or clipping objects, either importing or exporting, tools that are used on an illustration.

Importing Illustrator files works better if you lower the version of the illustrator files because the programs "retain" some newer features to the latest version of their programs. Sometimes it is better to use a "middle" format like PDF.

---

**It is not about "quality" it is about internal processes that are different**, they are treated differently in both programs.

So if the project is not finished, in either direction, importing or exporting on either program, your workflow can be interrupted.

If you have an illustration that needs to go to a cover of a book, for example, finish it on the program you are using, and when it is done, export it to an output format, like a flat PSD or TIFF and you can work ok.

---

So depending on what you need the files imported and exported can be 100% usable or can need some work.

Answer (score 0):

Since few versions, Corel Draw has natively provided support for Adobe Illustrator and Indesign files which means you can design in illustrator and open the file in Corel Draw and it will be open in it.

But it has its limits.

1) Sometimes the clipping path and open ended paths has to be tweaked in Corel.

2) The artwork sizes are more likely lost.

There might be several others, I encountered the above two.

When exporting from Corel to Illustrator, or photoshop you can choose EPS file format for vector and any lossless file format for images. EPS is natively supported by Illustrator. Again huge limitations are applied.

In short, they’re two rivals and don’t support each other. But over the time several possibilities have come to designers which weren’t possible few years ago.